# akka-spray-websocket template build error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, spray

I'm having a little problem with these template from TypeSafe, when I try to import it in IntelliJ I get following message error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-aspectj;0.10.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.5.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.timushev.sbt#sbt-updates;0.1.7: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.7.2 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-aspectj:0.10.1 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.5.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]      com.timushev.sbt:sbt-updates:0.1.7 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.7.2 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10) (C:\Users\jlopesde\akka-spray-websocket\project\plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:akka-spray-websocket-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-aspectj:0.10.1 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10) (C:\Users\jlopesde\akka-spray-websocket\project\plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:akka-spray-websocket-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.5.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10) (C:\Users\jlopesde\akka-spray-websocket\project\plugins.sbt#L5-6)
[warn]        +- default:akka-spray-websocket-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]      com.timushev.sbt:sbt-updates:0.1.7 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10) (C:\Users\jlopesde\akka-spray-websocket\project\plugins.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:akka-spray-websocket-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-aspectj;0.10.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.5.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.timushev.sbt#sbt-updates;0.1.7: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-aspectj;0.10.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.5.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.timushev.sbt#sbt-updates;0.1.7: not found
```

I know there is a problem on importing it, probably versions of Spray or Scala aren't correct but I don't know how to fix it. Could you provide me some tips for dealing with problems like that?

Thanks

My build.sbt:

```
organization  := "cua.li"

version       := "0.4"

scalaVersion  := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaV  = "2.3.9"
  val sprayV = "1.3.2"
  val kamonV = "0.3.5"
  Seq(
    "com.wandoulabs.akka" %%  "spray-websocket"       % "0.1.4"           withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-json"            % "1.3.1"           withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-can"             % sprayV            withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-routing"         % sprayV            withSources() withJavadoc,
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"            % akkaV             withSources() withJavadoc,
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-slf4j"            % akkaV             withSources() withJavadoc,
    /*
    "org.aspectj"         %   "aspectjweaver"         % "1.8.4"           withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.kamon"            %%  "kamon-core"            % kamonV            withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.kamon"            %%  "kamon-spray"           % kamonV            withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.kamon"            %%  "kamon-statsd"          % kamonV            withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.kamon"            %%  "kamon-log-reporter"    % kamonV            withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.kamon"            %%  "kamon-system-metrics"  % kamonV            withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.kamon"            %%  "kamon-testkit"         % kamonV   % "test" withSources() withJavadoc,
    // */
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-testkit"          % akkaV    % "test" withSources() withJavadoc,
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-testkit"         % sprayV   % "test" withSources() withJavadoc,
    "org.scalatest"       %%  "scalatest"             % "2.2.3"  % "test",
    "junit"               %   "junit"                 % "4.12"   % "test",
    "org.specs2"          %%  "specs2"                % "2.4.15" % "test",
    "ch.qos.logback"      %   "logback-classic"       % "1.1.2"
  )
}

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-encoding", "UTF-8", "-feature", "-target:jvm-1.7", "-unchecked",
  "-Ywarn-adapted-args", "-Ywarn-value-discard", "-Xlint")

javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:deprecation", "-Xlint:unchecked", "-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7", "-g:vars")

doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none")

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false

logBuffered in Test := false

Keys.fork in Test := false

parallelExecution in Test := false

seq(Revolver.settings: _*)

import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj._

aspectjSettings

fork in run := true

javaOptions <++= AspectjKeys.weaverOptions in Aspectj
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably missing the repositories to download the dependencies.

Try put this before libraryDependencies:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Spray repository"    at "http://repo.spray.io/",
  "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
)
```

Comment: same error as above.   [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-aspectj;0.10.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.5.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.timushev.sbt#sbt-updates;0.1.7: not found

Comment: I just dowload the template and put this resolvers to run:
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Spray repository"    at "http://repo.spray.io/",
  "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
)

Was missing the Scalaz repo. This worked for me.

Comment: I got a new dependency error:
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-rev
olver;0.7.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-aspectj;0.10.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.timushev.sbt#sbt-updates;0.1.7: not found

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue but only with sbt-revolver. I've managed to solve it by doing following:

My SBT is set up to use my Artifactory instance in order to retrieve dependencies.

1) In Artifactory I added the repository below to the "Remote Repositories" and made it part of the "remote-repos" virtual repository.

http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases

2) On my ~/.sbt/repositories file, I've made sure my Artifactory repository is configured with the correct URL format (please see below). I've taken the format from [SBT's documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html).

```
artifactory-ivy: http://my.artifactory.com:8081/artifactory/repo/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```